# Sailsjs fetch data from two different mysql databases

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I'm building a rest api using sails js v 1.x
I need to connect two mysql database so I have defined them in config/datastores.js file life this:

```
module.exports.datastores = {
 default: {
      adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
      url: 'mysql://root:12345@192.168.0.5:3306/test',
    },
    mysqldb: {
      adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
      url: 'mysql://root:12345@192.168.0.5:3306/test2',
    },

};
```

In my controller, I have this function which needs to get data by joining the database test as well as test2

```
module.exports = {

    index: function (req, res) {
        User.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery("SELECT * from test.users u INNER JOIN test2.users t ON u.id=t.id limit 10",function(err, rawResult) {
            res.send(rawResult);
        })
    },

};
```

But this gives me an error :

```
{
   "code": "ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE",
    "errno": 1146,
    "sqlMessage": "Table 'test.users' doesn't exist",
}
```

Also I have a blank User model and execution of raw sql queries work perfecty when the query is like `select * from users` (it uses the default database i.e test)
How do I achieve this kind of query by connecting more than one MySQL database in sails js?

Comment: select * from users works because `table users` exist, but table `test.users` obviously doesn't exist on default table. If i understand, u want join 2 tables from different databases?

Comment: see my answer. I was able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue this way :

my config.datastore file :

```
module.exports.datastores = {
 default: {
      adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
      url: 'mysql://root:12345@192.168.0.5:3306/',
    },

};
```

My controller :

```
module.exports = {

    index: function (req, res) {
        User.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery("SELECT * from test.users u INNER JOIN test2.users t ON u.id=t.id limit 10",function(err, rawResult) {
            res.send(rawResult);
        })
    },

};
```

Was having trouble figuring it out at first as there is no such example showing a join on multiple tables from different databases when using raw MySQL queries.

The only change I did is I just removed the database name from the default connection URL. Now I'm able to access all the databases on this particular server and also able to join multiple databases.

Comment: my config:
`
  default: {
      adapter: "sails-mysql",
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: "3306",
      user: "root",
      password: "mysql",
      database: "erp"
    }
`
my query:
`
let test = await Document.getDatastore().sendNativeQuery("
       SELECT d.id, dl.name_hrv from erp.doc_documents d 
       JOIN crm.common_documentLabels dl ON dl.id = d.label");
`
And all works, u can try this type of configuration of database. Let us know is this work for u.